# Get Manufacturer Image on Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm trying to add manufacturer image on **topmenu** module on prestashop. I'm very new to this CMS.
I added this line to the code (`blocktopmenu.php`) to make some tests:

```
<img src='.$link->getImageLink((int)$manufacturer['id_manufacturer'], 'img/m').'>
```

Unfortunately checking the HTML generated code, the link I obtain is the following, and it can't retrieve correctly the image I need:

```
<img src="abtemplates.altervista.org/1/img/m/2.jpg">
```

But what I need really is this:

```
<img src="/1/img/m/2.jpg">
```

**My Question:** Is there a way to obtain manufacturer image with `getImageLink` method or similar? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the manufacturer image with the following code:

```
<img src="' . __PS_BASE_URI__ . 'img/m/' . (int) $manufacturer['id_manufacturer'] . '.jpg">
```

It is more elegant to assign the manufacturer ID to a Smarty variable in the `hookDisplayTop` method:

```
$this->smarty->assign('id_manufacturer', $yourManufacturerId);
```

Then you can display it in `blocktopmenu.tpl`:

```
<img src="{$img_manu_dir}{$id_manufacturer}.jpg">
```

Comment: Oh, thanks it seems really more elegant. I don't understand properly what variable I must set where you wrote `$yourManufacturerId`. Because in that module I've `$manufacturers` that contains all manufacturers details, but I don't know ho to retrieve their ID

Comment: @Markviduka Do you want to display the image of all manufacturers?

Comment: Yes I want to display the image for each manufacturer on the top menu, near the manufacturer name

Comment: @Markviduka I am not sure that I understand you correctly. If you want to display the image of the current manufacturer on the manufacturer's page then: `$yourManufacturerId = Tools::('id_manufacturer');`. If you want to display the images of all manufacturers then:
`$manufacturers = Manufacturer::getManufacturers(); $manufacturerIds = array(); foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) { $manufacturerIds[] = $manufacturer['id_manufacturer']; } $this->smarty->assign('manufacturerIds', $manufacturerIds);`

Comment: @Markviduka And in `blocktopmenu.tpl`: `{foreach from=$manufacturerIds item=manufacturerId}<img src="{$img_manu_dir}{$manufacturerId}.jpg">{/foreach}`

Comment: This is what I'm looking for: "display the images of all manufacturers". Thanks a lot @yenshirak!